# Merging two python lists of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to take two lists, each of which are lists of dictionaries with the same keys, and output versions of each list that only contain dictionaries that share common values for one of the keys. For example:

```
#before:

json1 = [{'id':1, 'name':'john', 'age': 3}, {'id':2, 'name':'jack', 'age':5}]
json2 = [{'id':3, 'name':'john', 'age': 5}, {'id':1, 'name':'jill', 'age':3}]

#Do some operation that merges based on the key 'id'

json1 = [{'id':1, 'name':'john', 'age': 3}]
json2 = [{'id':1, 'name':'jill', 'age':3}]
```

So, merging the lists of dicts based on id would output what I wrote above. Merging based on another key, say 'name', would only keep the first dict of each list.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

**EDIT**
Sorry about the list names, I guess to be extremely accurate I'll call them json1 and json2

Comment: Why are your lists named dict1 and dict2? =/

Comment: What ID are you wanting to merge on? like i see you have id = 1 but what about if there are other ids that match? do you just want to pick one? use it as a set?

Comment: No other IDs match in the above example. Only the 0th index of the first json and the 1st of the second have matching IDs, so they will be the only dictionaries to survive to the output of each json. That's what I'm going for. It's not as much about matching a certain id=1, but more of just finding IDs that match in each json

Comment: so you just want to use a set then right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't hash a dictionary, what did you have in mind to make a set? I'd like to keep all the other information in each dictionary (like in the example, we keep the name and age info through the process)

Comment: What happened to jack (id 2)?

Comment: I'd have to think about it for a min because im not all that great at python yet (been learning it for the last month) but i would say make a function that you call that gets all of the id's (or whatever key you want to use.. you would specify) then find in the other dictionary, then remove from the first one. finding in the first one and removing would be using a set of id's that are in the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing your merging function could be something like that

```
def merge(key, l1, l2):
    k1 = { d[key] for d in l1 }
    k2 = { d[key] for d in l2 }
    keys = k1.intersection(k2)
    f1 = [ d for d in l1 if d[key] in keys ]
    f2 = [ d for d in l2 if d[key] in keys ]
    return f1, f2
```

That is :

- take values of the key used for merging (in your examples 'id' or 'name')
  in sets to avoid duplicates
- find common values in the 2 sets
- keep only dicts from the initial lists where the key take one of the common values

If you take `merge('id', json1, json2)` you get a 2-tuple of your resulting json1 and json2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand you, I'd do this in two passes: first find the common values, and then build the new lists:

```
>>> j1 = [{'id':1, 'name':'john', 'age': 3}, {'id':2, 'name':'jack', 'age':5}]
>>> j2 = [{'id':3, 'name':'john', 'age': 5}, {'id':1, 'name':'jill', 'age':3}]
>>> jj = (j1, j2)
>>> common = set.intersection(*({d['id'] for d in j} for j in jj))
>>> common
set([1])
>>> jjnew = [[d for d in j if d['id'] in common] for j in jj]
>>> jjnew
[[{'age': 3, 'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}], [{'age': 3, 'id': 1, 'name': 'jill'}]]
```

And similarly for `name`:

```
>>> common = set.intersection(*({d['name'] for d in j} for j in jj))
>>> jjnew = [[d for d in j if d['name'] in common] for j in jj]
>>> jjnew
[[{'age': 3, 'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}], [{'age': 5, 'id': 3, 'name': 'john'}]]
```